# How to get ranking from a scoreboard of 5million rows in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, ranking

I have a leaderboard which has a "score" column. I also have an index on the score column which allows me to order the table by score very quickly, even slicing out the top ten or any number of scores - even with 5 million rows!

However, what I would really like is to also display the players "rank" in the leaderboard. I have tried a few methods but none seem to stack up when dealing with anything over 100000 rows (they start taking over half a second, which is too long considering I'm expecting hundreds of cuncurrent users).

I'm currently using the following query to determin one users rank, then simlpy incrementing up for the users above this in my output - but it's very slow.

```
SELECT  tro.score, tro.userId,  
(
    SELECT  count(*) 
    FROM    scoreboard tri
    WHERE   tri.score >= :score
) AS rank
FROM test_tracks tro
WHERE userId = :userID");
```

I am thinking of generating a ranking table to "cache" the users rank whenever they insert a new score into the scoreboard, but even generating this will take a LONG time (minutes, possibly hours).

Does anyone know of any good guides or tricks to establishing rankings? Preferably I'd like to be able to pageinate the results too, but even just establishing rank for the moment would be sufficient!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use a table that is updated on a regular basis (once an hour, once a day etc) by a schedule that *can* take a longer query and run it. There isn't any need to smash the database all the time with those sorts of heavy queries. It also means that the long-running query is run once a while, not with every user that browses through o that page.

A perfect example is here on SO, where the [weekly/monthly/yearly](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow) totals are updated once per day.

Comment: I would love to see how they're doing it! But yes, the plan was to generate them periodically.

Comment: @AndyBarlow No matter how good the indexes, or the hardware, sometimes the cost of running a query is just too high and is vastly outweighed by running a single lengthy operation once an hour or once a day.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can suggest is the following. (It works for me on 5 millions rows, but it is not concurrency tested. It's REALLY slow in InnoDB for some reason, but works sub-second for in a MyISAM table, so transaction support would be lost.)

I created a table called ranks: ranks( score int PK, num int )
And then seeded it with this:
    insert into ranks(score,num) select score,count(*) from players group by score;

After that I created this stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE testranks(
     OldScore INT 
    ,NewScore INT 
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ranks (score,num) VALUES (NewScore,1) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE num = num + 1;
    UPDATE ranks SET num = num - 1 WHERE score = OldScore;
    DELETE FROM ranks WHERE num = 0 AND score = OldScore;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ranks WHERE score >= newscore;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

If you call TestRanks(with the old score and the new score) it will give you back the new rank.

I am keen to see what solutions others come up with.

Answer (score -1):

I have recently done the ranking against scores. I m posting the rough mysql code, which should guide you further.

```
SET @rank = 0, @prev_val = NULL;
SELECT id,rank, score FROM (
SELECT @rank := IF(@prev_val=score,@rank,@rank+1) AS rank,
@prev_val := score AS score, id
FROM rank ORDER BY score DESC
)AS result
```

Where table name is "rank" and fields are id, score

Hope this helps

Comment: This query didn't ever seem to complete with my large data set, even with limits inserted. Think something may be broken with it.